# Blackberry Mail

Tags: email, blackberry, service, blocking

Does any body knows how to disable Enterprise Email in blackberry using

```
net.rim.blackberry.api.mail
```

I tried many ways but didn't get any solution.

Comment: i have searched in many ways to get a solution . but didn't find

Answer (score 2):

Enterprise Email is served by a BES server and therefore subject to IT Policy controls. I would be very surprised if there is any way to disable this using the API. To remove a BlackBerry from the BES you must remove the IT Policy.